# Continue in catch block

Tags: c#, exception

Is this:

```
// retry
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    try
    {
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        if (e.Number == 64)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

equivalent to:

```
// retry
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    try
    {
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException e) { }
}
```

(since the loop will continue anyway in latter case)

What is the difference (if any)?

Comment: You only need `continue` if you have code after it, and want start at the top of the loop again.

Comment: Maybe you actually want `if (e.Number != 64) throw;`? It's kind of hard to tell what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: You really shouldn't continue the loop anyway once you get an exception. You really can't trust the state of the connection anymore.

Answer (score 10):

`continue` let you to skip the remaining statments in the current loop, and jump to the next iteration.

Given the code we have right now, it makes no difference. Since there is no more code after `if (e.Number == 64) { continue; }`.

Answer (score 3):

For all practical intents, the code segments are equivalent.  There is an edge case, however, that in principle should never happen: **what happens if the getter `e.Number` is evaluated and throws an exception?**  If this were to happen, the code in the first example would throw, whereas the second example would continue.

Given that a [property getter should never throw an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it's difficult to imagine this being a practical issue for .NET framework classes.  But for this reason, the segments are (strictly speaking) not identical.

Comment: Or, similarly, `e.Number` could have some other side effect when it's evaluated. Which is, of course, another edge case that should never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Both are identical !! But its not a good practice to have empty catch statement in your code .. The first piece of code is more appropriate .. you can add code to come out of the for loop or log an exception if the `if (e.Number == 64)`

Answer (score 0):

**Context:** There are 2 questions in your post:
1.Is codeA equivalent to codeB?
2.What is the difference (if any)?

**Solution:**

1. Yes, they are equivalent. [Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number) is a property of SqlException, so the getter e.Number will not throw an exception. Then:

   - Whether or not the number is 64, it will continue with next iteration of the for-loop (because there is no code after the "continue" instruction.)
   - Whether or not an exception occurs, it will continue with next iteration, because if an exception occurs, it is being caught.
2. There is no difference when executing both codes. But apparently, you want to  throw (to log the error, or to do something) in case the number is different than 64. Like @Blorgbeard's example:
   `if (e.Number != 64) throw;`

Finally, in both cases: codeA and codeB, if another type of exception occurs (different than SqlException) your code will throw an exception anyway.